# LocalStorage in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, local-storage

Has Firefox extension personal LocalStorage? And how can I get access to it?
I know  about `window.content.localStorage`, but it the specific localStorage of the current page, not like in Google Chrome, where each extension has personal background page.

Comment: What do you intend to do with localStorage? Most Chrome plugins use localStorage to store their preferences. Firefox has Preferences API for that purpose. The code would depend whether your addon is SDK based or XUL based.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [simple-storage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-storage.html) module for storing content specifically for your addon that is not bound to a specific page like localStorage, and you also can use the [indexed-db module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/indexed-db.html), which is a bit more robust, and we are kind of moving away from simple-storage.

Comment: One thing to point out with the [Add-on Builder Helper](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/) is that the simple-storage clears out every time you reload the extension. It made it extremely painful to test the extension and make changes in the code. I had to use the preferences as a backup, which was a huge headache and may have caused my extension to break. If you checkout this [StackApps FF extension](http://stackapps.com/q/3778/4812), you can see how this made simple-storage extremely unreliable during development. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 I agree, it does totally no sense to clear out all preferences from every extension debugging session. What is the logic of creating separate profile and debug with it? Mozilla team should get inspired a little from Chrome Extensions development process.

Comment: @teoman-shipahi Using either cfx or jpm, addon development tools for Jetpack, you can specify what profiles to use

Comment: but setting profile still not helps to keep storage persistent

Answer (score 3):

simple-storage would be an ideal solution, but if you're using the [Add-on Builder Helper](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/) it's not ideal because the storage gets flushed every time you make a change to the code and reload the app. Thus, it's impossible to test that your code works properly without actually building the extension and going to test it in another browser profile, making it hard to tweak the code and make minor changes.

Instead, I used the [simple-prefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-prefs.html) module, which *did* actually persist across restarts:

```
var prefs = require("simple-prefs").prefs;
```

The downside is everything has to be serialized as a string, so the development overhead is a little bit more complicated, but once you get it setup you can then test your code more easily without having to build the XPI for each minor change, something the Add-on Builder is supposed to help you avoid.

Comment: simple-storage gets flushed at each restart unless you pass the `--profiledir` argument to `cfx run`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage#Simple_storage_and_.22cfx_run.22

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#profiledir